# Rich Push Notification - Video won't play in Notification Content Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, rich-notifications

I am working on rich notification's `Notification Content Extension` and have able to load `images` and `gif` successfully like following screenshot:

[image]

Now i am trying to play video and i am doing following code for playing it.

```
- (void)didReceiveNotification:(UNNotification *)notification {
    //self.label.text = @"HELLO world";//notification.request.content.body;

    if(notification.request.content.attachments.count > 0)
    {

        UNNotificationAttachment *Attachen = notification.request.content.attachments.firstObject;


        NSLog(@"====url %@",Attachen.URL);
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:Attachen.URL];
        AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

        AVPlayer  *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
        AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
        playerLayer.contentsGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
        player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
        playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

            [self.VideoPlayerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
        [player play];
    }
}
```

In NSLog i get the file url of video as well. but that wont play. Kindly help if any one have that solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Very small mistake i did with the code that. we must be check with `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` if i do code like following

```
- (void)didReceiveNotification:(UNNotification *)notification {

    if(notification.request.content.attachments.count > 0)
    {
            UNNotificationAttachment *Attachen = notification.request.content.attachments.firstObject;

            if(Attachen.URL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource)
            {

                NSLog(@"====url %@",Attachen.URL);
                AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:Attachen.URL];
                AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

                AVPlayer  *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
                AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
                playerLayer.contentsGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
                player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
                playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.VideoPlayerView.frame.size.width, self.VideoPlayerView.frame.size.height);

                [self.VideoPlayerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
                [player play];

            }                
        }
}
```

And Video is playing. Boooom...

Comment: hi Guys can I play video in Notification Service Extension. If yes then How ?

- (void)didReceiveNotification:(UNNotification *)notification

did you this method in NotificationService.h or Appdelegate.h 

I am still confuse using Notification Service Extension I successfully download video but can not play video

Comment: @Nitin Hey I need your help. Can you help me ?

Comment: sure connect at skype nitin.gohel10

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your code. make sure the resource is downloaded to your disk.
2. If you want to play a url, you should get the url from the notification userInfo and play it in your Content Extension

To address the question asked in the comments by **Ankur patel**:

1. You should create a Notification Content Extension.
2. `- (void)didReceiveNotification:(UNNotification *)notification`
   is a UNNotificationContentExtension Protocol

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to play video in Notification in Swift 5.

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    let content = notification.request.content
    titleLabel.text = content.title
    subtitleLabel.text = content.body
    
    playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    preferredContentSize.height = 475
    
    // fetch your url string from notification payload.
    let urlString = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        guard let playerController = self.playerController else { return }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        playerController.player = player
        playerController.view.frame = self.playerBackgroundView.bounds
        playerBackgroundView.addSubview(playerController.view)
        addChild(playerController)
        playerController.didMove(toParent: self)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

There are some more conditions to use of Notification Content Extension, I hope you are following all of them.

Comment: AVPlayerViewController() is unknown. And many things are not described. Please descriobe it.

Comment: You can look into my article for full details. This is the working solution. Also, the complete code attached to this article.

Comment: Can you please share link to your full article ?

Comment: @YakirSayada Please find here https://nitinagam17.medium.com/customizing-the-appearance-of-notifications-in-swift-7cf36a544f98