# Rich notification play video clip

Tags: swift, rich-notifications

I'm trying to get rich notification and play video on the notification.
I success to show an image and not found swift sample code.

What need to be done to add video clip / mp4 notification support?
which function need to add to the NotificationService class ?

Thanks Yakir

Comment: It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/66205763/12783209 already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add extra code and no need to use AV player also. we can achieve that by initialising UNNotificationAttachment with url which we get after URLSession.shared.downloadTask

```
URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: attachmentURL) { url, _ , _ in
    let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "identifier", url: url, options: nil)
    content.attachments.append(attachment)
}
```

While updating the content in NotificationServiceExtension. Notification will load the video if it is video url.

**Note: -** please make sure video should be small size or as suggested by Apple.